# Match conditions with property name and value from JSON data

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

Lets say I have a table with rules in a SQL database with this structure:

```
Rule         Conditions                                 Action
------------`------------------------------------------ ---------------------
1            {"country": "USA", "state": "NY"}          DoActionOne
2            {"country": "France", "department": "55"}  DoActionTwo
```

These rules apply on my user. So state, country, department are properties that I can find in my user or user address definition. But these rule can be something else. It can be the date on creation of my user or something I don't expect right now.

How can I load this condition string and evaluate each rule, each condition with my user? I know how to retrieve the data from my database. I use Entity Framework but I don't know how to transform the string in a query or JSON object.

```
'NOT TESTED
For Each rule As Rule In dbContext.rules
    'Load condition one
    Dim condition = rule.Conditions.???
    If (MyUser[condition.Name] = condition.Value)
        ' DoAction
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little `Reflection` to achieve this.

Let's assume this is your `UserAddress` class

```
public class UserAddress
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Department { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

Then, assuming you have already read the `JSON` properly and got the list of rules as pair of strings (e.g. "country" & "France", "department" & "55" etc.), you can write the rule checking code as

```
var userAdd = new UserAddress { Country = "France", Department = 55, State = "SomeState" };
bool allRulesChecked = true;
foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    var property = typeof(UserAddress).GetProperty(rule.Key, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (property != null && property.GetValue(userAdd).ToString() != rule.Value.ToString())
    {
        allRulesChecked = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note, it won't work properly with complex types.